# What does . mean in a Matlab expression?

Tags: matlab, operators

From Matlab example of computer vision stereo depth estimation...

What is the purpose of the `.` in the last line below?

```
centroids_2D = [round(bboxes(:, 1) + bboxes(:, 3) / 2), ...
    round(bboxes(:, 2) + bboxes(:, 4) / 2)];

centroidsIdx = sub2ind(size(disparityMap), centroids_2D(:, 2), centroids_2D(:, 1));
X = point3D(:, :, 1);
Y = point3D(:, :, 2);
Z = point3D(:, :, 3);
centroids3D = [X(centroidsIdx), Y(centroidsIdx), Z(centroidsIdx)];

object_distance_meters = sqrt(sum(centroids3D .^ 2, 2)) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators `^` and `.^` are two different way to use the power

`A^2` means `A*A`

In the other hand,

`A.^2` means

```
A(1) = A(1)^2;
A(2) = A(2)^2;
A(3) = A(3)^2;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the element-wise power operator. Refer to the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) for more information and examples.